Do I need any transit visa or extra documents travelling from Kolkata to Nagoya via Hanoi and Hongkong? I might have separate airlines for this travel
Hi this is Sucharita from India. I am an Indian passport holder. Currently I am living in Nagoya, Japan for work purposes. I have CoE and visa and Zairiyu card for my stay in Japan and the residence certificate also......Now I wish to travel to Kolkata this December. however while returning from Kolkata to Nagoya, I am unable to get direct flight. So I am planning to take Indigo for Kolkata to Hanoi, and from Hanoi I wish to take Hong Kong Express flight(that will travel via Hongkong). So can you guide me if there is any additional documents required for this travel. because at Hanoi, I have to collect my luggage and might have to go through customs and all?

Transit without visa in Vietnam applies only if you can remain airside. Otherwise you’ll need an e-visa.
You can check your complete itinerary on IATA, and/or the visa guide published by Indigo.

Well my flight will be different, like from India I will be travelling via indigo. But at Hanoi I have to collect my luggage and I have to travel back to Nagoya using Hong Kong Express flight (which will fly via hongkong). So do you think I need transit visa for Hanoi? while transiting in Hanoi, the difference between my next flight would be 8 hrs approx.

If you have to collect your luggage you’ll need to clear Immigration. So you can’t remain airside, so you don’t qualify for TWOV.

Thank you for this information. It seems in that case I have to get and e visa.

Indian citizens may freely transit or visit Hong Kong without the need of a visa, provide that they complete the required pre-arrival registration.
